# Execute oncopy on body except certain class

Tags: javascript

I would like to execute a function on document.body.oncopy however there is a specific class (Defined to div elements), on which I would not like to call this function.

Is there some way of doing this?

Comment: Just add `oncopy` eventlistener for those elements, and prevent event bubbling to the `body` by adding `event.stopPropagation()` to those handler functions.

Comment: So the oncopy eventlistener will override the oncopy eventlistener for the complete body?

Comment: Yes, if they are just attached before for the `Body`. Actually it's easier to check the `className` of the `event.target` in the `oncopy` handler of the `body`, and then cancel the whole function, if the "specific" class is detected.

Answer (score 1):

As said in my comment, you can do something like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'specific') {
        return;
    }
    // Continue with all permitted elements
}
```